# typescript: exporting types when using 'export =' syntax

Tags: node.js, typescript

I need to add a feature to a code base that uses [typescript `export =` syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require). The code exports a function and adds properties to it:

```js
const f = () => {};
f.someVal = 123;
f.someFunc = () => {};
export = f;
```

So user can import the function directly in CommonJS \ ES style:

```js
const f = require('./my_module');
import f from './my_module'; // with esModuleInterop: true
```

But he can also import the attributes when needed:

```js
import { someVal, someFunc } from './my_module';
```

I want to export a type as well, e.g. user of this module should be able to:

```js
import type { SomeInterface } from './my_module';
```

How can I export a type using the `export =` syntax of typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use namespaces to do that:

```
namespace f {
  export const someVal = 123;
  export const someFunc = () => {};

  export type Test = { hello: string };
}
export = f;
```

---

EDIT: I just realized what you want to do is not possible. You cannot have types on a constant. There is already an issue in GitHub (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18163), but not yet implemented.

Comment: Thanks, but now f is not a function, it's a namespace

Comment: I tried the edit and I get `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'f'`. Maybe I need to configure tsc in some way for it to work?

Comment: Needs to be declared with `var`

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks, I changed to var and now tsc says: "error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'f'."